# Rails - importing Postgres production database to local development database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a database dump named dump.sql from production DB and when I try to import it to my local development DB I get an error

```
ERROR:  role "petdoctors_prod" does not exist
\connect: FATAL:  database "petdoctors_prod" does not exist
```

It looks like the name of the production database is `petdoctors_prod` and my local development db is called `petdoctors_development`. Is it possible to import prod DB to dev?

What's the best way of dumping the db from prod?

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should help in importing the `dump.sql` to your local machine:

1. Run `rake db:drop` from on your local machine to drop the existing database
2. Run `rake db:create`. This would create the database mentioned in your `database.yml` file as per the environment. In this case, it would create a database called `petdoctors_development`
3. Import the dump to `petdoctors_development`. This syntax of this step would vary depending on the database you're using. For example, to import a dump in PostgreSQL, we use `psql <db_name> < <Path to dump file>`
4. Run `rake db:migrate`, in order to run all the migrations in your app

Post this, the app will run on development, with the same data as that of the dump taken from production.

Comment: That's what I did, as mentioned in my question. `psql -U postgres petdoctors_development < ../dump.sql` raises the above error.

Comment: Are you sure the db was created using `rake db:create`? What happens when you type `psql petdoctors_development` in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I've just done that again. When I do `psql petdoctors_development` I get logged in to psql petdoctors_development database

Comment: Does `psql petdoctors_development < ../dump.sql` work? Usually running the command by mentioning the user results in an error on my machine as well since the default `postgres` user does not have permissions to access my Rails app databases.